# Вытащить текст из title регулярным выражением

Tags: php, функции

Этим кодом я хотел получить текст из title страницы:

```php
preg_match_all('#<title>\w+</title>#', file_get_contents("http://htmlbook.ru/"), $result);
print_r($result);
```

Но поиск происходит не в title, а в url страницы. Что мне делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут проблема не в тексте, поиск происходит как раз по тексту документа. У Вас проблема в самой регулярке.

Если Вы напишете регулярку вот так, результат будет верным, Вы получите заголовок:

```
preg_match_all('#<title>.*</title>#', file_get_contents("http://htmlbook.ru/"), $result);
print_r($result[0][0]);
```

`\w+` эквивалентно [a-zA-ZА-Яа-я0-9_]+. Т.е эта часть будет искать все соответствующие символы. В заголовке HTMLAcademy появляются ещё `|` и `.`, регулярка пропускает заголовок. Других заголовков нет – возвращается пустой массив. 
`.*` (или `.+`) будет принимать любые символы, значит можно не переживать за то, какой символ будет в заголовке не прочитан.

---

Также можете написать регулярку как `#<title>(.*)</title>#`, тогда в `$results` будете получать как рузультат с тегами, так и чистый заголовок.

Comment: Прошу прощения, может я что то не понял, но как не пробовал - этот код выводит пустую страницу.

Comment: @Ivаn Что значит выводит пустую страницу? Проверяйте, что делаете не так, код рабочий. https://i.imgur.com/ARS1dZl.png

Comment: Теперь понял : #<title>(.*)<\/title>#